# error in eRm itemfit

Tags: r

The code below gives me the following error message on my machine

```
Win7 64 bit    
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

It seems to me that others had similar problemes with no solution yet (http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/eRm-itemfit-td4695451.html).

However the code runs fine on R-Fiddle (http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=CH3gX07l&version=1)

```
library('eRm')
mod <- RM(raschdat2)
p.mod <- person.parameter(mod)
itemfit(p.mod)

trying to get slot "Data" from an object (class "ppar") that is not an S4 object
```

Any idea what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by reinstalling Hmisc, install.packages("Hmisc"), if that does not help I reinstall the whole "eRm" package, restart R.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated to R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) and that solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I loaded the updated eRm package, followed by the updated Hmisc pacakage, and that worked for me.